# Nodemailer error: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'contentTransferEncoding'

Tags: nodemailer

I'm trying to send a **POST** request from ***Unity to my web service endpoint in Node.js***; I'm able to send emails without adding any attachments. But, when I try to send an array of attachments I always get this error.

**Error**: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'contentTransferEncoding' in [{filename: 'test.txt', contentType: 'text/plain', content: 'Hello World!', contentTransferEncoding: 'quoted-printable'}]

I also tried to send a **POST** request from **Postman** but I get same error.

Comment: hi! can you please post the code related to your problem

Comment: I seem to be having a similar issue. The code is quite simple. the content is as the OP mentioned. This works when console logged using the "in" operator but somehow the same code withint nodemailer fails. The failing code is in nodemailer/mailcomposer/index.js line 97